# Autogenerate new reservation number for existing clients MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I need help. I am designing a library DB in Access and I am having some trouble with the book reservation and loan forms.

I have the following tables:

librarymember (LibraryMemberNumber is auto generate number PK)

BookReservation (ReservationNumber is autogenerate, datetime stamp and librarymember as FK to librarymember PK)

BookReservationDetail (ReservationNumber, ISBN, NOtified, cancelled and completed check box fields)

Books (ISBN as PK, Title etc)

My query is as per image below:

[main query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjGHu.jpg)

I can generate new records in the table but I want to generate new records in the form. I have set the data entry property to yes but when I select the field box and try to enter in a library member ID it throws an error letting me know that it cannot be edited as it is bound to the expression librarymembernumber. I just want the form to show only a new record, type the library number in, and the form to generate the next reservation number. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. First of all check Control Source properties of LibraryMemberNo and Total Reservated fields, you should not see error in those fields. LibraryMemberNo should contain query field, this field should not be calculated. Than check mater-child fields properties for subform with details.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have checked the control source and the two FKs point to the PKs of the correct tables. It's only an issue when the form is in data entry mode. It should just auto generate a new record but maybe because it has two FK's in the same form that is the issue?

Comment: I still get the same error with the library member field after removal of the reservation number field. The error is "Control cannot be edited; It's bound to the expression [librarymembernumber]". Librarymembernumber is an autonumber PK. Would that create an issue?

Comment: If you're adding a new reservation to your existing LibraryMember then have the LibraryMemberNumber be a drop down box allowing you to select from an existing LibraryMemberNumber.  (No need to have LibraryMember involved in this form, as BookReservation just needs that related field to be updated)

Comment: oh, didn't see @Sergey's answer below.  It's basically what he's saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have 3 entities, all one-to-many: Library Member, Book Reservation Header and Book Reservation Details. You are trying to create two entities at the same time in the same line of form, it's impossible for one-to-many relations.

You have at least two ways for resolution:

1. Keep existing Book Reservation form, remove Library Member from base query, Library Member FK convert to combobox and select Member using this combobox. For creating/editing of Library Members create a separate form
2. Create editing form for Library Member, as subform use form for editing Book Reservation, which has Reservation Details as a subform, so, you will have 3 tier form.

I would use variant #1, it's easier to implement and use. For Members editing add a command button.